# What's most elegant/secure/recommended way to solve "Response to preflight request " issue

Tags: angular, cors

I've done a research on SO on this, but to my surprise, lots of SO answers on this recommending a quick and dirty solution which is to turn off chrome's security!

I cannot believe we've got this as recommend solution. 
There must be a better way.

The error is this:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin

I'm on localhost and hitting a remote (IIS) server thru my http.post request.

Another answer is this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

What are the possible harms of going down this track?
(if we were to go with the above PHP headers )?

And what are the harms if we go down with Chrome's security cooling using this:

```
Note : Kill all chrome instances before running command
chrome-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Before I settle on one of these could someone explain the potantial harms or suggest a better way to not to compromise on the security to go over this hassle?

All I'm trying is to do an angular 2 httpService based http.post operation from localhost:4200 to a remote server that I must work with.

Comment: By default Chrome does not allow localhost to connect remote. There isn't a different option for this CORS issue when your client is hosted on localhost.

Comment: Z. Bagley, you mean a Chrome option? Would doing so, compromise on the security?

Comment: As long as you're only using this for your own personal application you do not need to worry about the security option (if you're unsure of the security of any plugins you'll want to disable those features while using this mode as well). The differences between toggling this option are already listed on this site, but there isn't anything major and nothing to be worried about when using to develop an application. Hope this helped.

Comment: So, assuming all plugins/extensions are from trusted sources, then it is OK to "disable-web-security" on the Chrome as long as you visit your own website. If so, this would make developers very vulnerable to b subjected to malicious attacks. All you got to do is to forget the fact that it web security is turned off. I cannot believe that one cannot set/list/pass the domain where this feature is to be disabled for. Do you happen to know of a plug in or an extension to say, if the remote server that Chrome is trying to xhr is so-and-so, only and only then apply `--disable-web-security`?

Comment: Not sure about yours, but mine does a huge yellow flag at the top while working with web security disabled, it only disables for that tab, and the security risks are fairly minimal when visiting trusted sources. The main problem is on completely untrusted sites (hopefully a rare occurrence to visit) as far as security. I'm also unaware of a plug-in, since all browsers must be closed before disabling web security for a window.

Comment: That yellow thing is pretty good and the fact that disabled mode applies to that tab only are big plusess  (at least in my eyes. ) I wish that that plugin allowed us to pass our whitelist of domains to apply the-disabling on but,.. that's a wishful thinking for now.. I'd like to ask you your opinion on one thing. I solved my problem like this and wondering if there is any security issues. I will post that in my next comment below:

Comment: Here is what I did on the PHP side ( and this has fixed that "pre-flight" error on the console - without any plugins or disabling anything on the chrome.  `  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
  } `  Is there any security implications with these headers that might make my php script vulnerable? In other words, do these headers make my script welcome any request coming from anywhere in the world?

Comment: I'm not 100% an expert on this, but I do know it's very bad practice to use a `*` for Access-Control-Allow-Origin value in *production*. As far as local development goes, this is pretty much the same thing that chrome is doing w/ the security option, but instead you're making this hop from your PHP server.

Comment: makes total sense. so I feel like I'm back to square 0.

Comment: If you're using `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, you can't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - you have to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value-of-origin-header}`.

Comment: Rory, can you give me a sample string of what would be for {value-of-origin-header}? Is there a conflict while having both? It seems to be working now for me. Is there any harm?